# Extracting IP from ping into variable in bat script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ip

is there anyway i could do this?

```
@echo off
REM #Testing FIND in IPCONFIG

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('ping localhost ^| findstr /i "reply"') do (
  set address=%%a
  set address=!address::=!
)

ipconfig /all | findstr %address%
if ERRORLEVEL = 1 goto VIP_NOT_FOUND

REM #We are here becuase the find returned a result.
REM #It is safe to execute the rest of the application.
REM #EXECUTES THE SCRIPT HERE

echo "testing works" >> testing.txt

:VIP_NOT_FOUND
REM #This part of the script is where you would handle any
REM #error logging or other admin related
echo "Could not find a VIP. - Exiting"
echo "end of script reached."
```

I am running this script on windows server 2k8 ENG version. It seems to keep on giving me findstr : bad command line. But i am not sure where the problem lies.

Comment: the final goal of your batch file is to ... ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor the final goal of my batch file is to run a script if the ip is mapped as a secondary ip on this current server.

Comment: Check your value of `%address%`. I suspect it is undefined because `ping localhost` is failing. That is the only scenario I can think of that would cause the FINDSTR %address%` command to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('ping myhost.com ^| find /i "reply"') do (
  set address=%%a
  set address=!address:~0,-1!
)

ipconfig /all | findstr "%address%" >nul && (
  rem Do stuff
)
```

If the host has IPv4 as well as IPv6 addresses and you're looking for an IPv4 address, use `ping -4` instead of just `ping`.

Comment: It shows an error of findstr: bad command line if i use findstr with /i in the bytes. But if i use your code, it throws up an error of file not found. I am running on windows server 2k8

Comment: See updated answer. I changed the filter to `reply` (may need adjusting for non-english versions) and fixed the address cleanup so that it doesn't choke on IPv6 addresses.